# Compute the difference in hours between dates values and integer values in list of lists in Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separate Pandas series, each containing a list of lists of the same length with over a million entries. Entries at the same position have the same data type: integer or timestamp. Most integer values are 0 and can be assumed to represent 0 hours.

I want to compute the difference in hours between each pair of items in similar positions in the two lists, and return that as a simple list of integers representing the diff in hours. Each sublist can have any number of elements in them, but they always match the number in the other.

For sublists with multiple items, we want to sum that difference as shown in my code in order to return one element.

Here's a sample of the values after running the head function on each series:

```py
dpt[0:10]

0                                                  [0]
1   [Timestamp('2017-06-10 14:50:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
2                                                  [0]
3                                                  [0]
4    [Timestamp('2017-06-10 14:50:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
5    [Timestamp('2017-02-16 08:37:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
6    [Timestamp('2017-03-06 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
Timestamp('2017-03-07 09:50:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
7                                                  [0]
8                                                  [0]
9    [Timestamp('2017-04-27 18:25:00+0000', tz='UTC')]

arr[0:10]

0                                                  [0]
1    [Timestamp('2017-06-10 06:20:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
2                                                  [0]
3                                                  [0]
4    [Timestamp('2017-02-10 09:03:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
5    [Timestamp('2017-02-16 07:40:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
6    [Timestamp('2017-03-06 16:35:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
Timestamp('2017-03-07 07:15:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
7                                                  [0]
8                                                  [0]
9    [Timestamp('2017-04-27 16:25:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
```

Here's the function I have tried, which returns as expected and the outputs are correct **but is very slow**:

```py
def layover_hours(dpt, arr):
    f = []
    for i in range(len(dpt)):
        dpt_ = list(dpt)[i]
        arr_ = list(arr)[i]
        r = []
        for j in range(len(dpt_)):
            d = [dpt_[j]-arr_[j]]
            r.extend(d)
        f.append(r)
    d =[]
    for x in f:
        if type(x[0]) == int:
            d.append(sum(x))
        else:
            d.append(sum(x, datetime.timedelta(0,0))/np.timedelta64(1,'h'))
    return d
```

**Sample run:**

```py
layover_hours(dpt=dpt[0:10], arr=arr[0:10])
```

**Sample output:**

```
[0, 8.5, 0, 0, 1.95, 0.95, 6.0, 0, 0, 2.0]
```

What I need is help refactoring my code or a better solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Pandas approach

```
# Join the two series on common index
s = dpt.to_frame('dpt').join(arr.to_frame('arr'))

# convert items in the lists to individual rows
s = s.explode(['dpt', 'arr'])

# claculate the difference
s = s['dpt'].sub(s['arr'])

# boolean mask to check if the value is not integer
m = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').isna()

# calculate hours by dividing timedelta values by 1 hour
s[m] = s[m] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

# aggregate the exploded lists back to rows using sum
s = s.groupby(level=0).sum().tolist()
```

---

```
[0, 8.5, 0, 0, 2885.7833333333333, 0.95, 6.0, 0, 0, 2.0]
```

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Sharma, for you answer. I will a take a closer shortly but one thing that struck me right away is that your output values are different from me. The 5th entry to my result list is 1.95 but yours is 2885.7833333333333, which is not correct. Thanks for taking a second look.

Comment: Glad to help @user2217673 I think the 5th value should be `2885.78` you can validate by executing your code on the given sample it will produce `2885.78`

Comment: thanks again. I rerun my code and it doesn't return that value, it return my initial outputs. Please use the below entries and check again.

dpt[0:10] ->

[0]
,[Timestamp('2017-06-10 14:50:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[0]
,[0]
,[Timestamp('2017-02-10 11:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[Timestamp('2017-02-16 08:37:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[Timestamp('2017-03-06 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2017-03-07 09:50:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[0]
,[0]
[Timestamp('2017-04-27 18:25:00+0000', tz='UTC')]

Comment: arr[0:10] -> 
[0]
,[Timestamp('2017-06-10 06:20:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[0]
,[0]
,[Timestamp('2017-02-10 09:03:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[Timestamp('2017-02-16 07:40:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[Timestamp('2017-03-06 16:35:00+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2017-03-07 07:15:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
,[0]
,[0]
[Timestamp('2017-04-27 16:25:00+0000', tz='UTC')]

Thanks again for your help. Sorry for the poor formatting here.

Comment: @user2217673 but in your orginal sample te values are different :-) Check row 5 in both dataframe

Comment: is that right?!? so do you get my initial outputs with the latest sample input? So about at that. I will check again now. Thank you so much!

Comment: yes it should work as expected.

Comment: It worked indeed. Thank you so much! I will accept your answer now. You saved me countless hours :-)